# How to check if a byte array is a valid image?

Tags: c#, image, .net-4.0, arrays

I know there is no .Net function that exists for checking, but is there an algorithm or easy and effective way of checking if a byte is a valid image before I use the byte array. I need this because I'm sending different commands to a server who is constantly listening to the client and one of the commands is to get the screenshot of the server's computer.

Comment: Each image has a header in a certain format.  You can always check that.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can try to generate an image from the byte array and check for the `ArgumentException` if its not.

```
public static bool IsValidImage(byte[] bytes)
{
    try {
        using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
           Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException) {
       return false;
    }
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as "checking before I use the byte array"

Comment: This is a very common pattern for python programming, you ask for forgiveness instead of permission: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain)

Comment: @BenVoigt unfortunately i guess there is no way to check if the bytearray represents a valid image without reading it.

Comment: @anion: Possibly true, but one should at the very least use the `Image` object after you've done all the work to convert it, not throw it away and have to repeat the work later.  That's what the TryXXX pattern is all about.  In this case a good function signature could be `bool TryConvertImage(byte[] input, out Image result)`

Answer (score 13):

As noted, trying to load it into an image is the only fail-safe way. You can check the magick number aka file header based on the [expected] image type. For instance, the first 8 octets of a *.PNG file are, in hex:

```
0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47 0x0D 0x0A 0x1A 0x0A
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header

Most other types of image files have similar magick numbers.

But checking that won't actually tell you if the file is a valid image file. All you'll know after that is that the magick number seems to indicate that its a file of type X. It could still be truncated or otherwise corrupted, or even be something else entirely that just happens to have the right sequence of octets in the right place.

Answer (score 4):

For a JPEG you can check that the first two bytes are 0xFF, 0xD8 and the last two are 0xFF, 0xD9. Of course its still possible that the image data will match the EOI tag, but this should be rare.

Answer (score 0):

I created a converter method for this problem.

**Method:**

```
public static bool TryConvertImage(byte[] imageBytes, out Image image){
    try
        {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
        {
            image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
        return true;
      }
    catch
    {
        image = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
if(TryConvertImage(myImageBytes, out Image convertedImage){
     // Use the convertImage object as you wish.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

According to me, if you want only image input(Proper image), then you should go with accept attribute of input field like this:

input type="file" name="uploadedFile" id="imageContent" class="required" accept="image/*"/>

This will give you only images in input. So, you can freely code for backend. Without worrying about the image is valid or not.

And even you can specify specific image type if you want like:

input type="file" name="uploadedFile" id="imageContent" class="required" accept="image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png">

Comment: This assumes the user is a non-malicious user, the browser properly supports these attributes properly, and a couple of other things to consider. ALWAYS secure your back-end as much as possible, as client-side validation is, sadly, unreliable.