# screenshot in cucumber-jvm looks small

Tags: json, selenium, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to take screenshot from cucumber-jvm using this code .

```
      if(scenario.isFailed()){
        try {
            scenario.write("Current Page URL is " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
            byte[] screenshot = getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
            scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");

        } catch (WebDriverException somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots) {
            System.err.println(somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Then i will take the report.json and parse it to cucumber sandwitch jar . The Screenshot embedded successfully . But it appears very small . In default cucumber-jvm output html file , it appears good .

Does the size of the image caused by Json byte code ? . Can we make it appear in full size ?

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790275/resize-image-which-is-placed-in-byte-array)